# Links are not opening in default browser(Brave) in Linux Mint

Tags: firefox, browser, linux-mint, brave

I have Brave set as my default browser. But when I try to open links from some from some app, they open in Firefox. links from apps and documents are opening in firefox. This includes Telegram, Mail reader(mail spring), pdf viewer(zathura, document viewer) etc.
Most of the links are opening in firefox when opened from outside the browser. Even jupyter notebook opens using firefox when launched from terminal.
An ss of my preferred applications: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szbb2.jpg

```
Nitro-AN515-52:~$ inxi -Sxxxz
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.13 
           info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 

Nitro-AN515-52:~$ update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser 
gnome-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link currently points to /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link gnome-www-browser is /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable - priority 201
/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable - priority 200
CODE: SELECT ALL

Nitro-AN515-52:~$ update-alternatives --display x-www-browser 
x-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link currently points to /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link x-www-browser is /usr/bin/x-www-browser
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable - priority 201
/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable - priority 200
```

Comment: Try using `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` and 
`sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser`